# Is there a way to manually bring up the keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

I am trying to play a Pico-8 game in my browser that requires keyboard Inputs but my keyboard does not appear. Is there a way to manually bring up the keyboard or have it on permanently?

Comment: Keyboard can be brought forward manually, but I think the keyboard has to have a screen pinning or overlay-like functionality to continue to be up and resist being brought down. Try asking at [softwarerecs.se]. See if somebody there knows a keyboard with this feature.